# Browse button issue - Asset Picker

Tags: 2013, permissions, deployment, administration, asseturlselector

I just did a Backup - Restore of a site collection from one farm to another. On the destination after the restore, the "Browse..." is no longer working - the one that is used to navigate within SharePoint libraries e.g. site settings - Title, Description and Logo - From SharePoint and I get the following error:

> Sorry, something went wrong - An unexpected error has occurred

In ULS log I see the following for the corresponding correlation ID:

> SQL connection time: 0.0622984206093233 bb729c9c-2658-c0b4-d54e-11f9ad9dad06
>   AssetPickerDialog.ConfigureChildControls - start bb729c9c-2658-c0b4-d54e-11f9ad9dad06SQL connection time: 0.056711118312523 bb729c9c-2658-c0b4-d54e-11f9ad9dad06
>   SPRequestParameters: AppPrincipal={0}, UserName={1}, UserKye={2}, RoleCount={3}, Roles={4} bb729c9c-2658-c0b4-d54e-11f9ad9dad06
>   SQL connection time: 0.0491682602118426 bb729c9c-2658-c0b4-d54e-11f9ad9dad06

Couldn't figure what went wrong. Any ideas please.

Answer (score 0):

try the following:

- Restart IIS and SharePoint timer job
- Clear config cache
  http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jamesway/archive/2011/05/23/sharepoint-2010-clearing-the-configuration-cache.aspx

I still an issue restart the server.